# RabbitMQ Obj-C client connection status check

Tags: objective-c, connection, rabbitmq

I'm using [rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client). Is there a way how to check if connection was opened successfully? I see there is RMQConnectionDelegate but there are only methods that are called when an error appears. I'm looking for something like

```
RMQConnection *conn = [[RMQConnection alloc] /*...*/];
if ([conn isOpen]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
[conn start:^{ // code to execute when connection established }];
```

But note that the client is async and all channel operations are placed onto a queue for execution after the connection is established.

I've added a note to the issue Michael opened: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/issues/101