# how can i know rabbitmq connection is busy

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to create rabbitmq connection add in `list<connection>` like a connection pool, but how can I know my connection is busy or no busy. I read rabbimtmq code find `sessionManager`, but not public.so. Help me I am new coder. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

This should show you the status of  rabbitmq. Let me know what you get.

Also an alternative try, if that's what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234367/5381704